# How to configure the php.ini of cloud9-ide

Tags: php, cloud9-ide

I want to configure the php.ini of the c9,but I noticed that seem didn't take effect.After searching by Google I knew it needs to restart php-fpm,but I can't find this application in my workspace.How I do next?thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer from the new community discourse forum: 
https://community.c9.io/t/customizing-php-ini/1487

> bradydowling Cloud9 Employee Jan 22, 2016
>
> For PHP, you can create custom
>   configuration by editing /home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini. For example,
>   from the terminal, from the following commands:
>
> create custom php.ini `$ echo "display_errors=Off" > /home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini`
>
> verify it is found `$ php --ini` Loaded Configuration File:  `/home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini` You may also just create a new file in
>   your workspace folder and name it php.ini and then open that by
>   double-clicking it.

and also this other forum post on the topic for complete reference of past discussion: https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-configure-my-php-ini-file/642/2?u=mikeumus

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop your project and then start again (menu Run/Stop, then Run/Run last) - Apache webserver will restart with new PHP configuration.

Comment: you can also start/stop apache from the terminal in Cloud9 using `apachectl stop/start` etc.

Comment: Where is the php.ini file located? I cannot find it in c9. And how do I open it?

Comment: How to change the Apache? server port from Cloud9?